# Laravel - Pivot Table / Relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, relationships

I'm quite new to programming and am struggling to understand how I should specify the eloquent relationships.

I've created a website where there is an event called a "hangout" and a "join" button which allows users to join the event, thereby attaching their user_id to the hangout_id via a pivot table.

Right now I'm very confused as to how I should/can:

- specify the relationships between hangout and users;
- for a single hangout, display a list of users attending;
- for a single user, display a list of hangouts created; and
- for a single user, display a list of hangouts they are attending?

Users can create many hangouts, i.e. hasMany, but when they click "join", they also belongToMany hangouts.

Whilst hangouts can only belong to one user but can have many attendees/users.

Can someone point me in the right direction? This is what I have so far...

**User.php**

```
public function hangouts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Hangout');
}

public function attending()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hangout');
}
```

**Hangout.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function attendees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

**Users Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->boolean('admin');
    });
}
```

**Hangout Table:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('hangouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('price')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('hangout_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('hangout_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('hangout_id')->references('id')->on('hangouts')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your table structure for user and hangouts ?

Comment: Added as requested. Thanks for assisting!

Comment: How you are confirming that user is attending the hangout? Have you maintain the status for it or it is simply if we have record in `hangout_user` table with the user id and hangout id it means that user is attending that respective hang-out.

Comment: It's simply a record in the hangout_user